# If statement doesn't check the image sizes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, if-statement

I'm looking through some old `angularJS` code written by previous developers, and I found an `if statement` that checks if the image is in 1:1 or 16/4 or 4/3 sizes and if yes then the image can be uploaded.

When I try to upload an image in 16/4 or 4/3, however, it simply refuses to upload, as if it isn't in the if. Only the 1:1 ratio works.

My question is how could I rewrite the code to make it work?

```
  $scope.$watch('file', function (val) {
        if (val != undefined) {
            if (!val[0].isImage) {
                $scope.errorMsg = 'It must be an image';
                $scope.disabled = true;
            }

            // This is the if that doesn't work well
                let ratio = Math.ceil(val[0].width / val[0].height);
                if (ratio == 16 / 9 || ratio == 4 / 3 || ratio == 1) {
                    $scope.errorMsg = '';
                    $scope.disabled = false;
                    $scope.saveFile();
                } else {
                    $scope.errorMsg = 'Your selected image must have the given ratio. (16:9 or 4:3 or 1:1)';
                    $scope.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: `Math.ceil` returns an integer. 16/9 and 4/3 aren't integers. `ratio == 16 / 9` and `ratio == 4 / 3` are always `false`.

Answer (score 3):

When dividing numbers JS (or pretty much any other language) has a precision that uses. This means that results may differ a bit from the math results.

You should use a range when doing comparisons like this. So instead of expecting to be exactly `16/9` you should expect to have an error.

You also need to remove the `Math.ceil` from your ratio computation.

You can use [epsilon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON) for this. Something like this maybe:

```
if (Math.abs(ratio - 16 / 9) < Number.EPSILON || Math.abs(ratio - 4 / 3) < number.EPSILON || ratio == 1)
```

Another approach would be to just drop the division and only use multiplications. Something like this

```
 if (val[0].width * 9 === val[0].height * 16)
```

This will not have a precision problem.

Comment: This answer allows the perfect image proportion size, you might want to give a little space and allow images really close to required proportion. It depends on how hard should be your restrictions.

Comment: I agree with you. But in the end it depends on the reqs though. I assumed that it needs perfect proportions.